# Button alignment changing on click of it - extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

There are 3 divs, each having a panel in them. Initially, only 2 panels are displayed and the other is hidden. On clicking 'Update' in one of the panels, these 2 div are hidden and the 3rd one is shown.
There is a set of buttons in the 3rd panel. The below is the code for it

```
buttons: [{
        xtype: 'checkbox', id:'usapCheck', boxLabel: 'I Accept', allowBlank: false, margin: '1 1 4 230'
 },{
        buttonAlign: 'right',margin:'0 0 0 3.6',text: 'Save',width: '30',iconCls: 'save',
        handler: function() {
            //code to save form details
        }
    },{
            buttonAlign: 'right',margin:'1 1 0 3.6',text: 'Clear',width: '30',iconCls: 'clear',
        handler: function() {
            //code to clear the fields
        }
    },{
        buttonAlign: 'right',margin:'1 1 1 1.6',text: 'Back',width: '30',iconCls: 'back',
        handler: function() {
            //code to hide this div and show other divs.
        }
    }]
```

When I click the back button, the 3rd panel is hidden and displays the 2 other grids in the same js. But when I again click the 'update' button, to display the 3rd panel, the alignment of these buttons change.
So, on hiding and showing the panels, the alignment changes in a strange way.
I am totally lost, without any clue. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: I changed the `buttons` to `bbar` and worked in both mozilla and IE. Thank you for the help anyway. Stupid of me to try with buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head:

You shouldn't use `buttonAlign: 'right'` there and your `width` is set as a String for all your buttons, using ExtJS, when you specify your `width` value as String it works like CSS values, so you have to pick:

```
width: 30 // 30 pixels
// or
width: '30px' // 30 pixels
```

Correct this and your buttons shouldnt look messed up anymore.

Comment: +1. Thank you, I removed the buttonAlign property and it works fine in Mozilla but not in IE. In IE, the `I Accept` is written in 2 lines, that is, the text wraps and the button alignment is also hampered with.

Comment: I changed the `buttons` to `bbar` and worked in both mozilla and IE. Thank you for the help anyway. Stupid of me to try with buttons.

Comment: But check out this fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/cc6. Removing the quotes around the width values and removing the buttonAlign made it work perfectly.

Comment: Appreciate your help, thank you very much. The bbar looks better than the buttons actually. So, I settled with the bbar

Comment: Also I accept this answer because you proved it using fiddle example.

Comment: Just for future reference, the buttons config is the same thing as adding a toolbar with `ui: footer` and a component with `flex: 1`. You can see this in the doc here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-buttons